How can I keep a WordPress dropdown menu open when navigating to a child page?
I'm using WordPress with the Astra theme (free version), along with Elementor Header & Footer Builder (free version) and the WP Mobile Menu (free version). I've set up a dropdown menu, but it closes automatically when I navigate to a child page within that dropdown. I want to keep the dropdown menu open when users navigate to any of the child pages.

You'd probably have to set a custom JS cookie and then write a script to check if the dropdown was open (via the cookie) and if it was, trigger a pseudo click or hover to trick the dropdown into re-opening.
